# How to force phdthesis bib entry to expand to Ph.D. (and not to PhD) in the bbl?

Tags: bibliographies

The bib entry:

```
@phdthesis{w-ieaem-07,
  author      = {Ron Wein},
  title       = {The Integration of Exact Arrangements with Effective Motion Planning},
  school      = {Tel Aviv University},
  year        = {2007}
}
```

expands to:

```
\bibitem{w-ieaem-07}
R.~Wein.
\newblock {\em The Integration of Exact Arrangements with Effective Motion Planning}.
\newblock PhD thesis, Tel-Aviv University, Israel, 2007.
```

in the bbl file. How can I enforce

```
\newblock Ph.D. thesis, Tel-Aviv University, Israel, 2007.
```

?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Answer (score 10):

It seems that you are using the standard `\bibliographystyle{plain}` command. In this case there's little you can do, since the `PhD` is hard wired into plain.bst.

A solution is to copy the file `plain.bst` as, say, `xplain.bst` in your work directory, edit it to change the (unique) string `PhD` into `Ph.D.` and call

```
\bibliographystyle{xplain}
```

in your document.

Answer (score 7):

You can override this with the "type" field in the .bib file:

```
  type = {{Ph.D.} Dissertation},
```

Simplest solution if it is just a few entries.  I have this line in all my theses in my bib file so I don't have to worry about what will happen by default.  (Works for any bib style I have tried, including plain.)